# Red5 2-way camera setup (videochat)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, red5

I got a problem with RED5 in combination with Flash. For a personal project i am trying to make a Skype-like application. I already got a application that records the users webcam and saves it with a custom filename on the RED5 server.

But i am stuck trying to connect one more user to that window for a video chat. I made a new video container in Flash but i don't know how to connect a second client to the same stream in AS3 with Red5?

I searched on the net but i only get really old threads about RED5 in combination with Flex.

[image: Maby this is helping understanding my problem?]
*Maybe this is helping understanding my problem?*

Could someone help me out? Or get me in the right direction?

Comment: Are user2 and user1 streams encoded into 1 stream?

Comment: That was the way i wanted it, i now know that's nearly impossible. I am using an FMS server right now instead of Red5. Since i am not a Flash AS3 scripter i hired someone to do this for me because i couldn't find any good Red5 or FMS support. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'm also trying to know if it's possible...can you keep us posted?

Answer (score 2):

Video chat? You will need 2 streams, for every client. Inbound and outbound. Outbound is a stream from the client to the media server, inbound is consumed stream of another user. So it will look like:

```
_streamOut = new NetStream(connection, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);
_streamIn = new NetStream(connection, NetStream.CONNECT_TO_FMS);

_streamOut.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStreamOutNetStatus);
_streamIn.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStreamInNetStatus);

_streamOut.attachAudio(microphone);
_streamOut.attachCamera(camera);
_streamOut.publish(hostPeerID);
_streamIn.play(companionPeerID);
```

Also there are [some helpful examples](http://www.red5.org/downloads/simpledemos/), did you check them?

Comment: In this chat, is any video file creation (recording) happening at the server side? Or, is the incoming stream in real time going to the outgoing stream and nothing get stored in the server?